# Does using onclick on div's effect SEO?

Tags: seo, html, javascript, accessibility

I have a few elements on my page that uses onclick as the link, e.g:

```
<div class="service" onclick="location.href='<?php echo $fields->service_1_link; ?>'" style="cursor:pointer;">
   <img class="service" src="<?php echo $fields->service_1_image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $fields->service_1_name; ?>" height="111" width="299" border="0" />
   <div class="service-title"><h2><?php echo $fields->service_1_name; ?></h2></div>
</div>
```

Does this have an impact on crawlers and SEO over say a normal link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Google's answer: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=81766

> When creating your links, format them
>   so that they'll offer a static link as
>   well as call a JavaScript function.
>   That way you'll have the AJAX
>   functionality for JavaScript users,
>   while non-JavaScript users can ignore
>   the script and follow the link. For
>   example:

```
<a href="ajax.htm?foo=32" onClick="navigate('ajax.html#foo=32'); return false">foo 32</a>
```

> Note that the
>   static link's URL has a parameter
>   (?foo=32) instead of a fragment
>   (#foo=32), which is used by the AJAX
>   code. This is important, as search
>   engines understand URL parameters but
>   often ignore fragments. Since you now
>   offer static links, users and search
>   engines can link to the exact content
>   that they want to share or reference.
>
> While we're constantly improving our
>   crawling capability, using HTML links
>   remains a strong way to help us (as
>   well as other search engines, mobile
>   devices and users) better understand
>   your site's structure.

Comment: So that pretty much says not to use it in the way I have!

Comment: Just noticed the updated answer - I've updated my question - how would I create that link from the code I've created? Whilst keeping it all semantically correct of course.

Comment: You seem to want an image with some text on top, both of which are clickable. You'd be better off creating a normal text link which has the image as a CSS background. That way no JS is required, and it will work for users and robots alike.